# How can I free disk space on the device to get it back into communication?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

IOS 13.3.1 bricked my IPhone XR after reporting IPhone storage is full

So, as you might guess, here is the most obvious question: How can I free disk space on the device to get it back into communication?

- I followed the disk full dialog - no effect
- I try to sync - not possible
- I try to backup - not possible
- I try to delete stuff - it shows up no more, but frees no diskspace
- I try a better mac - not possible, trust wont work
- I try to move pictures to the cloud - not possible (Error occurs while doing this)

Comment: See if the trial version of [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) can access your device. You can first try Image Capture to remove image/video files to see if that helps.

Comment: I have an older version of iExplorer, I removed images with that. Did not change the free disk space, though.

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem.

Comment: The next thing to try is to [Restore your iPhone to default settings](https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/restore-to-factory-settings-itnsdb1fe305/mac) to see if that helps. It'll nuke the contents of the iPhone, but should leave you with a working device, unless, of course, the iPhone has been physically damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone is back to accessible.

I had to reboot the device. After an endless time of waiting for the UI to come up again, the device came back.

It showed an non genuine battery warning. Reboot again.
The iPhone seems back to normal, but it is not recognized when connected to the mac. Reboot again.

The device is now properly recognized and all the deleted apps are now synced into iTunes. A warning pops up, that Music is missing (correct, I deleted it).

Some images are not recognized by Photo app to be not yet imported. I need to move them in a new album, then they are synced.

Still three movies left on the device, Photos app on mac shows error on import. 
2 of them can be copied as file over iCloud. Third persists to leave the device. I will either delete it or just leave it where it is.

Be warned: On my iPhone 11 this reboot completely bricked the device, so this reboot is not without risk.

The latest iOS endangers your unsaved data if you run out of disk space.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete the Applications that you purchased from the AppStore.  You can download them again for free. Also, delete the  Applications you don't need.  If you go to Settings/General there is an option that reads iPhone Storage. Open that and give it time to completely load. At the bottom, it will give you a listing of all your applications and the size of them. Check and see if you can delete any of the large ones.

Comment: I already did that, the problem is, that the apps vanish, but the space is not reclaimed. Even after removing Music and Udemy with all the downloads, I can neither sync nor backup the device.

Comment: Apple's Music was 0.6G alone. Also, of course I tried to remove deleted pictures, but the 2GB of deleted pictures keep coming back. The data is not deleted

Comment: Some of that stuff may be in iCloud. That's why I suggested Apps. The apps are stored on your iPhone.  Also 1 very small apps may not effet things enough to show up. Find the largest apps and delete them.  Or a bunch of smaller ones.

Comment: I appreciate your idea to delte the apps, it does not help. Believe me. I suspect I have to reboot the device to get something moving. But on another phone, the device was completely bricked afterwards. No reboot possible had to put it into DFU and ended up at smartmod but without success.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't help you more.